# how to separate source code and data while minimizing directory changes during working?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

This is a general software engineering problem about working on Linux. Suppose I have source code, mainly scripts. They manipulate text data, take text files as input and output. I am thinking about how to appropriately separate src code and data while minimizing directory changes during working.  I see two possibilities:

1. mix code and data together. In this way, it minimizes directory transitions  and eliminating the need of typing paths to files during working. Most of the time I just call:

   ```
   script1 data-in data-out # call script
   vi data-out # view result
   ```

   The problem is that as the number of code and data files grows, it looks messy facing a long list   of both code and data files.
2. Separate code and data in two folders, say "src" and "data". When I am in "src" folder, doing the above actions would require:

   ```
   script1 ../data/data-in ../data/data-out # call script
   vi ../data/data-out or cd data; vi data-out # view result
   ```

   The extra typing of parent directories "../data" causes hassle, especially when there are lots of quick testings of scripts.

You might suggest I do it the other way around, in the data folder. But then similarly I need to call ../src/script1, again a hassle of typing prefix "../src". Yeah, we could add "src" to PATH. But what if there are dependencies among scripts across parent-child directories? e.g., suppose under "src" there are "subsrc/script2", and within script1, it calls "./subsrc/script2 ..."? Then calling script1 in "data" folder would throw error, because there is no "subsrc" folder under "data" folder.

Well separation of code & data, and minimizaing directory changes seem to be conflicting requirements. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Could you not just hard-code the path into the script? So instead of calling 'script1 ../data/data/input1', just call 'script1 input1'

Comment: For some of them, I can. Even though, if I use relative path, I need to run script in src folder, then switch to (cd or switch window) data folder to view the results, which brings a directory transition overhead. Using absolute path may work, but it seems also a hassle to hard coding absolute path in the script.

Comment: It is, and it also breaks any portability to pieces. You could always use a config script when moving to a new machine, though.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `cd -` facility of the shell plus setting the PATH to sort this out — possibly with some scripts to help.

I'd ensure that the source directory, where the programs are built, is on my PATH, at the front.  I'd `cd` into either the data directory or the source directory, (maybe capture the directory with `d=$PWD` for the data directory, or `s=$PWD` for the source directory), then switch to the other (and capture the directory name again).  Now I can switch back and forth between the two directories using `cd -` to switch.

Depending on whether I'm in 'code work' or 'data work' mode, I'd work primarily in the appropriate directory. I might have a simple script to `(cd $source_directory; make "$@")` so that if I need to build something, I can do so by running the script.  I can edit files in either directory with a minimum of fuss, either with a swift `cd -` plus `vim`, or with `vim $other_dir/whichever.ext`.  Because the source directory is on PATH, I don't have to specify full paths to the commands in it.

I use an alias `alias r="fc -e -"` to repeat a command.  For example, to repeat the last `vim` command, `r v`; the last `make` command, `r m`; and so on.

I do this sort of stuff all the time.  The software I work on has about 50 directories for the full build, but I'm usually just working in a couple at a time.  I have sets of scripts to rebuild the system based on on where I'm working (`chk.xyzlib` and `chk.pqrlib` to build in the corresponding sets of directories, for example; two directories for each of the libraries).  I prefer scripts to aliases; you can interpolate arguments more easily with scripts whereas with aliases, you can only append the arguments.  The `(cd $somewhere; make "$@")` notation doesn't work with aliases.

Comment: "Because the source directory is on PATH, I don't have to specify full paths to the commands in it." Well, if I have some scripts with the same name, then this won't work. Suppose I am experimenting with 2 slightly different methods, I create 
"mtd1" and "mtd2" folder as the src for two methods, respectively. It is common to have mtd1/script1, and mtd2/script1.

Comment: If you insist on making life difficult for yourself, then life is more difficult for you than for me.  I'd make sure that the two methods have different names, at least while testing.  When I've decided which is 'best', I'd fix the name.  In the interim, maybe you use different aliases (e.g. `s1` for the script in `mtd1` and `s2` for the script in `mtd2`), or use `script1-1` as a link to `mtd1/script1` and `script1-2` as a link to `mtd2/script1`.  The idea is to make your working life easy; different things need different names.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little more coding, but can you set environment variables from the command line to specify the data directory?

```
export DATA_INPUT_DIR=/path/to/data
export DATA_OUTPUT_DIR=/path/to/outfiles
```

Then your script can process files relative to these directories:

```
# Set variables at the top of your scripts:
in_dir="${DATA_INPUT_DIR:-.}"   # Default to current directory
out_dir="${DATA_OUTPUT_DIR:-.}" # Defailt to current directory

# 1st arg is input file.  Prepend $DATA_INPUT_DIR unless path is absolute.
infile = "$1"
[ "${1::1}" == "/" ] || infile="$DATA_INPUT_DIR/$infile"


# 2nd arg is output file.  Prepend $DATA_OUTPUT_DIR unless path is absolute.
outfile = "$2"
[ "${2::1}" == "/" ] || outfile="$DATA_OUTPUT_DIR/$outfile"

# Remainder of the script uses $infile and $outfile.
```

Of course, you could also open several terminal windows: some for working on the code and others for executing it.  :-)

Comment: Good suggestions! In this way, I can work in code directories, and call scripts as if data are in some relative paths. But still, after executing scripts, I need to cd or switch window to view the result in data folders. Could it be possible that it works like I call scripts in data folders, and view results at the same data folder?